# Pycharm "no module named REPORT.py" however it exist and works. But then

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

Pycharm says REPORT.py file doesn't exist. However the code works perfectly.

Here is the image of the issue:

[image]

Now that is not the strangest part. I know sometimes when you working within a package you have to reference the package name: `import package_name.filename` so when I tried that it appears to have fixed the incorrect reporting.

[image]

But then...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/REDACTED/PycharmProjects/REDACTED/MAIN/MAIN.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MAIN.REPORTS as PDD
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\PycharmProjects\REDACTED\MAIN\MAIN.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MAIN.REPORTS as PDD
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MAIN.REPORTS'; 'MAIN' is not a package
```

This seams like a mistake with how Pycharm is checking for my file.

For the sake of completeness I also tried to import from.

[image]

Pycharm is also not marking this as invalid but I get a new interesting error when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/REDACTED/PycharmProjects/REDACTED/MAIN/MAIN.py", line 2, in <module>
    from MAIN import REPORTS as PDD
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\PycharmProjects\REDACTED\MAIN\MAIN.py", line 2, in <module>
    from MAIN import REPORTS as PDD
ImportError: cannot import name 'REPORTS'
```

As request in the comments here is my folder structure:

[image]

Per suggestion in the comments I did try to import * but I still get the same reporting issue from Pycharm.

[image]

Update:

I believe I found out why the issue existed when trying to import from my package.

Due to my package name being `MAIN` and my main py file being `MAIN.py` I believe my code was trying to import from the py file and not the package.

After renaming my package to `MAIN_PACK` and doing `import MAIN_PACK.REPORT as PDD` the code works fine without any reporting from Pycharm saying it is not valid.

That at the vary least fixes the Pycharm reporting.

> However that still does not explain why Pycharm reports that `import REPORTS` is not a module but still the code would work.Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: Would be nice to get some feedback on the downvote. This appears to me to be a valid question and one that I have not found a duplicate for here on SO.

Comment: What is the folder structure for your project?

Comment: @R.Arctor I have added the folder structure to the question.

Comment: I have had a similar problem before. I think it was because the `__name__` is `__main__` of your main script page. Try `from REPORTS import *`

Comment: Getting the code to work was not an issue. The issue was the incorrect report from Pycharm. `import REPORTS as PDD` does in fact work perfectly fine but Pycharm says it does not exist in the IDE. The question was "why" does Pycharm report like this when the code does work as exspected.

Comment: @Barb For the sake of completeness I did test you idea and I still get the same bad reporting from Pycharm telling me REPORTS does not exist but the code does work.

Comment: Have you set the main folder as the source root? You can do that by right clicking the MAIN folder and navigating to the bottom of the list. Mark the directory as source root. Go into Pycharm settings under console and check **add source roots to python path**

Comment: @Barb that has removed the Pycharm reporting and my code works as expected. Do you have a resource I can read that explains what the source root is for? Honestly I have never heard of that before. I would like to try and found out why adding to source root fixed the reporting.

Comment: Basically Pycharm uses the source root as first protocol to resolve imports. Should be down this page somewhere https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html

Comment: @Barb looks good. If you want to write up an answer I will accept it. This is good info as far as my questions is concerned. This part looks like the specifics I was looking for from the link you provided `The files under the source roots are interpreted according to their type. PyCharm can parse, inspect, index, and compile the contents of these roots.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the main folder as the source root. You can do that by right clicking the MAIN folder and navigating to the bottom of the list. Mark the directory as source root. Go into Pycharm settings under console and check **add source roots to python path.**

Pycharm uses source root to resolve imports. More information can be found here

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html

Relevant text from link:

> Source roots (or source folders; shown as the Source root icon ).
>
> - These roots contain the actual source files and resources. PyCharm    uses the source roots as the starting point for resolving imports.
>        The files under the source roots are interpreted according to their    type. PyCharm can parse, inspect, index, and compile the
>     contents of    these roots.

Comment: I added the relevant text from the link. You want to do this when using links for reference just in case the links break down the road.